# Why does node webkit crash when downloading a big file?

Tags: node.js, stream, download, node-webkit

Im using node webkit 0.7.5 (which is the only version so far which allows me to display video in a correct way). 
I'm trying to download a big video file (200+ mb) and sometimes, not always, node webkit crashes when the file is done downloading. Writestream.end() is called, and that is when the crash happens.
My code:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require("request");
var req = request(self.requestOptions(), function (err) {
    if (err) {
        //handle error
    }
});
req.on("response", function (response) {
        writeFile(response);
});

function writeFile(response) {
    var file = fs.createWriteStream(filename);
    var self = this;
    response.on('data', function (data) {
        file.write(data);
    });
    response.on('end', function () {
        log.debug("response end");
        file.end();//crash happens after calling this
    });
    response.on('error', function (err) {
        //handle error, not called in this situation
    });
    file.on('finish', function () {
        log.debug("file finish");
    });
}
```

In general this method works excellent, but with some files and situations node webkit just decides to call it quits.
Am I doing something obviously wrong? I've searched the net for possible clues or solutions, but I haven't found anything.

Comment: I think better to use curl for big files there is a lib https://github.com/chriso/curlrequest